# Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-min-sdk

When I try to build the apk, I get this error :

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1] C:\Users\taha\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\eff6e7bdbf3eaa269c101b27c652fb15\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.messaging" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Here is the gradle build.  I tried to update SDK version from 27 to 28 and it didn't work:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId ''

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please explain your question rather than giving just errors..

Comment: Hi mkmtools, welcome to Stackoverflow. The information your provided is not sufficient. Try updating your question with a clear problem statement, share relevant code and the error you are facing and the things you have tried on your own to fix the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Google Play services blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-play-services-discontinuing.html), Google Play services and Firebase, including the `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` library have moved to a `minSdkVersion` of 16. You'll need to change your `minSdkVersion` to 16 or move back to an older version of all of the libraries.